# Plots next to other

Tags: r, ggplot2

With the following lines of code I product a graph:

```
chol <- read.table(url("http://assets.datacamp.com/blog_assets/chol.txt"), header = TRUE)
ggplot(data=chol, aes(chol$AGE)) + 
    geom_histogram(breaks=seq(20, 50, by =2), 
                   col="red", 
                   fill="green")
```

with the same way I produce 6 plots.

How is it possible to have this six plot in the same image in the first line have the 3 and in the second above the first have the other 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grid.extra` does this job

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

chol <- read.table(url("http://assets.datacamp.com/blog_assets/chol.txt"), header = TRUE)
p1 <- p2 <- p3 <- p4 <- p5<- p6 <- ggplot(data=chol, aes(chol$AGE)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(20, 50, by =2), 
                 col="red", 
                 fill="green")

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, ncol=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is using `cowplot`.

```
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6, ncol = 3, align = "v")
```

[image]

You can also adjust the height of each row if you would like using `rel_heights` inside the `plot_grid`command. Row 1 will be half the height of row 2.

```
plot_grid(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6, ncol = 3, align = "v", rel_heights = c(1,2))
```

[image]

Or you can adjust the width of each column using the `rel_widths`. Column 1 will be half the width of columns 2 and 3

```
plot_grid(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6, ncol = 3, align = "v", rel_widths = c(1,2,2))
```

[image]